# How to debug Node.js crashes after the crash event on FreeBSD 8.2?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I have a Node.js HTTP server running that counts things (results are stored in MongoDB using Mongoose). Here it is, in brief:

```
    var Elbrus = (function() {

            var my = {},

            my.try = function(testId, tag) {
                    var testresult = new TestTry();
                    testresult.testId = testId;
                    testresult.tag = tag;
                    testresult.save();
            };

            my.score = function(testId, tag) {
                    var testresult = new TestScore();
                    testresult.testId = testId;
                    testresult.tag = tag;
                    testresult.save();
            }

            return my;
    }());

    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
            var urlObj = url.parse(req.url, true);
            if (urlObj.query["score"]) {
                res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/gif'});
                Elbrus.score(urlObj.query["testId"],urlObj.query["score"]);
                res.end();
            }
            else if (urlObj.query["try"]) {
                res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/gif'});
                Elbrus.try(urlObj.query["testId"],urlObj.query["try"]);
                res.end();
            }
    }).listen(8080, "myserver.com");
```

TestTry and TestScore are Mongoose models.

This server will run for some hours, sometimes up to 12, and then crash. How can I begin to understand what the issue is? I'm on FreeBSD 8.2 and do not have mdb, although I do have gdb.

Comment: Does it give you an error message when it crashes?

Comment: There is really no way to answer this without knowing more details about the crash. Do you have logs or a stack trace? Was it node itself that crashed or a database issue? Were there any resource spikes (CPU/disk/memory) when the crash occurred? You might want to also catch more errors in your server and log them, like this:

`server.addListener("error", function(err) {

  console.log("server caught 'error' event:", err);

  console.log("stack", err.stack);
})`

Comment: I do not get any output to stdout when it crashes, but (sometimes) I get a core dump. Why I don't always get a core dump I have no idea. It is node itself that crashes, mongodb stays up without issue. I will add that listener! Thanks.

Comment: You can also analyze the core dump. See the [FreeBSD handbook - Debugging](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/debugging.html) for more info.